# Shapefile points, individual editing

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, fields-attributes, editing

I am very new to QGIS and have run into a problem dealing with shapefiles.

Recently, I went into the field with an app for smartphones called 'SW Maps' that I used to create some basic layers for lines and points. Under the 'point layer' I have three different types of points (I know I should have separated them when I created the layers).

Now  that I'm home, in front of the computer, I exported the shapefiles and loaded the data into QGIS.
Everything looks good, except for that I want to change the symbols and colors of the points so I can categorize them according to what they are.

The problem is that when I change the attributes to one point, it changes all the rest. I am not sure how to split(?) each individual point so I can edit them accordingly without having to create a duplicate, editing the color and symbol, making sure all the attributes copied over, and then deleting unwanted duplicates.

Does anyone know the best way to work around this? Or a good tutorial video on this type of editing? Or will I have to duplicate and edit individually?

Comment: Do the points have attributes that differentiate them? If they do, you can symbolise the layer by categories, i.e. by attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Multipart to Singleparts…` from the menu Vector, see:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts

Comment: This didn't work. It just made a duplicate layer that copied all the point attributes. So now I have a layer with about 80 points that are 'linked.' (Whenever I try and just change the color of the one point, it'll affect the 79 other ones.) But after I did the 'Multipart to Singleparts' algorithm, it just made a whole new layer with 80 points that are linked. When I try to change the color of the one point, it affects the rest.

Comment: Can you share your data? Can you add a screenshot? Can you give more details? Otherwise it's difficult to see where the problem is.